# Extend ArrayList<E> when E is a nested class of the ArrayList itself...is this wrong?

Tags: java

First this IS a Java question so forgive this first C#-related explanation...

I've most recently been using C# where one .cs source file can contain multiple class definitions, example...

```
// Servers.cs

public class Server {
}

public class ServerList : ArrayList <Server> {
}
```

I do the above because it reduces the number of source files and keeps the two classes together.

In Java of course it's one class to one .java file but I had the idea of nesting the Server class as follows...

```
//Servers.java
public class ServerList extends ArrayList<ServerList.Server> {

    // Edited to make Server class 'static'
    public static class Server implements Serializable {
    }
}
```

This builds without compile time errors or warnings but I can't decide if it's right.

The more I look at it, the more I'm happier with it but I'm still worried that it may be considered bad practice or I could run into problems along the line.

So the question...is this OK to do? Sorry if this is a rookie Java question (or even a rookie OOP question - despite using OOP going back to mid 1990s with C++, I'm self taught and have never tried something like this).

**EDIT:**

Many thanks to all who have provided comments/pointers to this question.

Firstly I've edited my code to make the Server class static - I expect I would have discovered this down the line but it's good to know from the start that I should be approaching it this way.

To expand on things related to other comments...

I have reasons for extending ArrayList rather than using ArrayList (or List) in associated code. I didn't include the code (haven't started yet) but ServerList will encapsulate specific handling of Server objects (including searching on Server-specific fields/members).

Also I'm using ArrayList rather than List as I'll be using an instance of ServerList to bind to an Android Spinner widget (nice and easy with an ArrayAdapter). Sorry I didn't mention Android but my question was (in my mind) specific to Java practice and not really to my choice of classes to achieve what I'm looking to do.

As for extensibility / inheritance etc with respect to other programmers (or myself) using the Server or ServerList classes at a later date, they really are quite specific to the requirements of my current project...not necessarily a good OO approach to class definition I admit (and not usually my approach) but they serve my project best in terms of usability and efficiency.

Thanks again to all.

Comment: the only thing is it will be `namespace.ServerList.Server`. if you can live with that, it should be fine.

Comment: Why do you need a class `ServerList` ? I would just use `ArrayList<Server>` whenever I needed a list of servers...

Comment: "In Java of course it's one class to one .java file" - not strictly true. As with your C# example, in Java you can include more than one class in a single source file.

Comment: In your C# code, `Server` is an outer class while in java, it's an inner class. Why?

Comment: In Java, it's one `public` class per .java file, to be precise.

Comment: @Péter Török: Thanks for clearing that up - I knew somewhere along the way I'd seen something about one class to one java file. Your comment clarifies this and I'll remember that for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mirror your first example more closely, you should make your inner class static:

```
public class ServerList extends ArrayList<ServerList.Server> {

    public class static Server implements Serializable {
    }
}
```

That means that the inner class can be created independently and is not related to the outer class. Otherwise, each inner class would be linked to its outer class (and would have access to those class' members as well) and would therefore be required to be created from within the context of ServerList.

Answer (score 3):

I have two issues with this:

- since `Server` is the important class here, it should be a top level class. Having it as an inner class IMHO makes your code unintuitive, harder to understand. (And as @EboMike pointed out, whichever way you do it, the inner class should be `static`.)
- I don't see a good reason to subclass `ArrayList<Server>` - apart from creating an extra class of minimal use, this ties its implementation to `ArrayList`, which limits your future options. I would prefer declaring `List<Server>` on public interfaces - *program to interfaces, not to implementations*. It is just as readable as `ServerList`, and more usable, since any Java programmer will know what it is, and how to use it.

Comment: I can understand your first point although I'm struggling to decide which of the two classes is indeed the most important. The ServerList class is what the user will interact with for configuration purposes and it's also what background code will use to decide the most suitable Server to use at any given time. On the other hand, the Server class itself will ultimately be what is used for creating a network connection. If it comes to it, I'll simply separate the code but it is useful to have one point of reference to the two classes.

Comment: @MisterSquonk, my point is that a list is just a collection of *things*, and those things are what ultimately are important for the clients - a collection is (usually) just a container to keep the bunch from falling apart. Background code will pick the most suitable server based on its properties I assume, not on the list's properties.

Answer (score 1):

I can be perfectly fine to nest classes. Try searching google for nested classes:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip75.html

That is a good article on it. But to answer the question, no it is not "bad practice" but there are specific times you will use it.

Answer (score 1):

It is technical perfect legal do do this, if you have a good reason.

For example the Java Map Interface do something (not 100%)  similar: It has an Inner Interface `Map.Entity`, and defined an entry set, that uses this Inner Interface (`Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()`) .

Anyway, you should make the inner class static, if you do not need access to the outer class within the inner one.